# Call Stored Procedure in C# MicroSoft Report Viewer

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005

i have create 18 Stored Procedure , and i want to call then when i design a new Report but in the Retrieving data step only the tables appears but there is no Stored Procedure 
and i am using SQL 2005 and VS 2008 Professional Edition

Comment: i don know if i did any thing wrong when i created the Stored Procedure

Comment: Are you talking about Sql Server Reporting Services?

Answer (score 0):

When creating a new dataset in your reporting project, you have the ability to change the command type to a store procedure. Enter the command in the query string text box with your parameters.